# WPF datagrid Cell color depending on preivous cell value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, colors, cell

Background.

I am developing a stock trading application.
Which obviously have a market watch.
I am developing this market watch using `Datagrid`.

What Does the Grid do?
It displays price points of a stock.
Every time a stock value increases the particular cell foreground turns green
if it decreases it turns red.

What i did?
I tried to use the value converter method and multibinding

Problem.
The value converter gives the current value only.
How can i pass the old value to that converter.

Code:

```
 <wpfTlKit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpfTlKit:DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource  myHighlighterConverter}" 
                                      >
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"></Binding>
                                <Binding Path="Row" Mode="OneWay"></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="OldData" Path="Rows"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </wpfTlKit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Converter

```
public class HighlighterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[1] is DataRow)
        {
            //Change the background of any cell with 1.0 to light red.
            var cell = (DataGridCell)values[0];
            var row = (DataRow)values[1];
            var columnName = cell.Column.SortMemberPath;

            if (row[columnName].IsNumeric() && row[columnName].ToDouble() == 1.0)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSalmon);

        }
        return SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this object val)
    {
        double test;
        return double.TryParse(val.ToString(), out test);
    }

    public static double ToDouble(this object val)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the color in a DataGrid cell I recommend the following:

Build a Model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged that contains the current, and previous price plus a property that reflects the change in the price (I've attached the full model at the end of this answer).

```
public double ChangeInPrice
{
  get
  {
    return CurrentPrice - PreviousPrice;
  }
}
```

And set the Background of the CellTemplate in your DataGrid based on the change in price using a Converter.
Note: INotifyPropertyChanged helps to change the color of the cell when the price values change.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock 
      Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPrice}" 
      Background="{Binding Path=ChangeInPrice, Converter={StaticResource backgroundConverter}}" >
    </TextBlock>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(SolidBrush))]
public class ObjectToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    SolidColorBrush b = Brushes.White; 

    try
    {
      double stock = (double)value;
      if (stock > 0)
      {
        b = Brushes.Green;
      }
      else if (stock < 0)
      {
        b = Brushes.Red;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }  

    return b;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Here is full model for completeness:

```
public class Stock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Stock(string stockName, double currentPrice, double previousPrice)
  {
    this.StockName = stockName;
    this.CurrentPrice = currentPrice;
    this.PreviousPrice = previousPrice;
  }

  private string _stockName;
  public String StockName
  {
    get { return _stockName; }
    set
    {
      _stockName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("StockName");
    }
  }

  private double _currentPrice = 0.00;
  public double CurrentPrice
  {
    get { return _currentPrice; }
    set
    {
      _currentPrice = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPrice");
      OnPropertyChanged("ChangeInPrice");
    }
  }

  private double _previousPrice = 0.00;
  public double PreviousPrice
  {
    get { return _previousPrice; }
    set
    {
      _previousPrice = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("PreviousPrice");
      OnPropertyChanged("ChangeInPrice");
    }
  }

  public double ChangeInPrice
  {
    get
    {
      return CurrentPrice - PreviousPrice;
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

well i think the problem is not the datagrid, but the object you bind to. if you bind to a datatable the oldvalues are built in (DataRowVersion). if you have other entity objects, then this entities need to support the original and modified values.

Comment: thanks, but can you provide me with an example. being new to WPF i dont understand how to bind objects to datagrid.

Comment: I don't think `DataRowVersion` is the solution. That's useful when you need access to version received from database and the local modified version. What the OP wants is old value from database and new value from database.